# I am trying to create a webpage with a PHP form. What is wrong about my code?

Tags: php, forms, fopen

Here is my form, located in `index.php`:

```
<form method="post" action="newpage.php">
    File name: <input type="text" name="filename"><br/>
    File extension: <input type="text" name="fileext"><br/>
    Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br/>
    Body: <textarea style="height: 3em; width: 50em;" name="body"></textarea>
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

As you can see, this routes the results to `newpage.php`.  Here is `newpage.php`:

```
<?php
    $file = "/app/filecreation/newfiles/" . $_POST["filename"] . "." . $_POST['fileext'];
    $writefile = fopen($file, 'w') or die('unable to open');
    $code = "<html><body><h1><?php echo $_POST['title']; ?></h1><p><?php echo $_POST['body]; ?></body></html>";
    fwrite($writefile, $code);
    fclose($writefile);
?>
```

I am trying to create a file when the `index.php` form is submitted.  For some reason, it is not creating a file as I would like.  Is there something wrong with this code that it doesn't work?

Pls help!! Thanks so much!

Comment: It's **highly** unlikely that `/app/filecreation/newfiles/` is a valid path. Do `echo getcwd();` to see what path your PHP file is located at, and work from there. Turn on your PHP error reporting so you can see the reasons it fails.

Comment: @ceejayoz thank you. I will look into that. Btw, does everything else look right?

Comment: Use single quotes, or put `$_POST['title']`, and `$_POST['body']` in quotes, so when the PHP re-executes it is valid. I also hope this isn't going to be open to the public. Also the file will need to have the `PHP` extension to execute as PHP, so maybe don't have `$_POST['fileext']` and just statically put `.php`. Also put the POSTs in curlys so they are complex, or concatenate them.

Comment: @Matt No, everything else doesn't look right. **This code is horrifically insecure** and (if it worked) would allow any random person on the Internet to put malicious code on your server. Frankly, the best thing about this code is that it's broken. Imagine this: someone submits `$_POST['title']` with a value of `''; exec('rm -rf /')`, for a resulting `<?php echo ''; exec('rm -rf /'); ?>` sitting there on your server waiting to be run.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have `error` in your line please change your line with this

```
$code = "<html><body><h1><?php echo $_POST['title']; ?></h1><p><?php echo $_POST['body]; ?></body></html>";
```

change into

```
$code = "<html><body><h1><?php echo '".$_POST['title']."' ?></h1><p><?php echo '".$_POST['body']."' ?></body></html>";
```

also make sure `file_exist` according to path `$file`. You can do this

```
if(file_exist($file)){
write your code here....
}
else{
echo "file not exist";

}
```